# What does "all the more" mean and how is it used?

Tags: meaning

Here is a sample context:

> As you might expect, the framework also provides some convenience
>   classes to make the task of writing custom validators **all the more** agreeable.

(Emphasis added.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general answer seems to be that *all the more* is an idiomatic way to say *even more* (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_the_more). Of course, that raises the question of the comparative -- even more than what? My sense is that in the phrase *all the more*, this is often (always?) left implied, and that *all the more* is really just an intensified version of *more*.

Comment: If X is made "all the more agreeable", it implies that X was already fairly agreeable to begin with, or that it was made more agreeable by something else previously addressed in the discourse, and this new thing makes X even more agreeable than that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess *all the more* is meant to mean [!] *that much more*, more in proportion to something else. Like: if you are kinder I'll love you all the more.