# Using adjectives with 'All the more'

Tags: grammar, phrases, adjectives

I'm trying to complete this dialogue but I've encountered a bit of trouble with the usage of 'all the more'. The dialogue is below.

> Our bond is based on trust. We have no contract.
>   Trust? Then all the more ___ for me to break it.

Should I put the word: easy, easier or easily in the blank space?

Comment: Have a look at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/what-does-all-the-more-mean-and-how-is-it-used

Comment: Also see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_the_more